# make battery warning appear on top

Tags: battery

> How can I make the low battery message appear on top of all running windows?

For example it happened that I watched a movie and the computer suspended because the battery was low, but the warning messages were not visible while watching the movie.

Comment: What are you using for playback?

Comment: I consider this a bug either for unity messaging system or the battery indicator: a notice about low battery should always be shown over the video. I use VLC and will have to check later today but I am sure I get a notice when the battery is on a low charge.

Comment: I am using VLC or Movie Player, but in both of them the warning doesn't show. It seems strange, becaus in older versions of Ubuntu the warnings did show up on top.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature.

If you want this you will need to code it yourself by hacking the software that is used to create and show themes. And I believe you will need alot of coding experience to pull this of.